# Hyperparameter Tuning FB Prophet Model - How to reference m.add_seasonality Categories in Parameter Grid

Tags: python, time-series, hyperparameters, prophet

I have a feeling this is more of a basic python question, but I'm struggling to find an answer on how to reference these additive regression components.

The FB Prophet documentation says to build a parameter grid with all of the setting configurations that you want to pass iteratively into the model to determine the combination that generates the lowest amount of error, which I have done (partially):

```
param_grid = {  
                'changepoint_prior_scale': [[0.005, .01, 0.05, 0.5, 1, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 ,90, 100],
                'changepoint_range': [0.8, 0.9],
                'holidays_prior_scale':[[0.005, .01, 0.05, 0.5, 1, 5, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80 ,90, 100]],
                'seasonality_mode': ['multiplicative', 'additive'],
                'growth': ['linear', 'logistic'],
                
              }
```

Facebook documentation here for reference: https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/diagnostics.html#hyperparameter-tuning

The documentation only explains how to hyperparameter tune the standard python model features, there are no examples for how to pass iterative parameters for "added" regression features that the Prophet model supports.

Here's an example of my relevant code:

```
M = Prophet(
    growth='linear',
    #interval_width=0.80,
    seasonality_mode= 'multiplicative',
    daily_seasonality=False,
    weekly_seasonality=False,
    yearly_seasonality=False,
    holidays=Holidays
    ).add_seasonality(
        name='monthly',
        period=30.5,
        fourier_order=50,#25
        prior_scale=20
    ).add_seasonality(
        name='daily',
        period=1,
        fourier_order=70,#25
        prior_scale=20
    ).add_seasonality(
        name='weekly',
        period=7,
        fourier_order=50,
        prior_scale=60
    ).add_seasonality(
        name='yearly',
        period=365.25,
        fourier_order= 30)
```

I'm wondering how to appropriately refer to something like "Monthly Fourier_Order" and "Monthly Prior_Scale" in my parameter grid. I tried Monthly.fourier_order and it didn't work.

I'm assuming this is probably a basic python referencing problem vs something Prophet specific. I'm just not sure how to correctly reference these additive features.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
m = Prophet(weekly_seasonality=False)
m.add_seasonality(name='monthly', period=30.5, fourier_order=5)
forecast = m.fit(df).predict(future)
fig = m.plot_components(forecast)
```

ref link : https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/seasonality,_holiday_effects,_and_regressors.html

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are lookin for seasonal parameters to enter, but there doesn't seem to be a *monthly* seasonal component. I'm not sure you could add one using the `add_seasonality(name='monthly', period=30.5, fourier_order=5)` method since that is added *after* the model is created and the `param_grid` loop through the parameters of the model.

Try:

```
 param_grid = {  
'changepoint_prior_scale': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 0.5],
'seasonality_prior_scale': [0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0],
'seasonality_mode': ['multiplicative', 'additive'],
'growth': ['linear', 'logistic'],
'yearly_seasonality':[5,10,20,40],
'weekly_seasonality':[5,10,20,40],
'daily_seasonality':[5,10,20,40],
}
```

Here are all the parameters available based on the source code from the [Prophet GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/main/python/prophet/forecaster.py):

- **Parameters**

  - **growth**: String 'linear', 'logistic' or 'flat' to specify a linear, logistic or
    flat trend.
  - **changepoints**: List of dates at which to include potential changepoints. If
    not specified, potential changepoints are selected automatically.
  - **n_changepoints**: Number of potential changepoints to include. Not used
    if input `changepoints` is supplied. If `changepoints` is not supplied,
    then n_changepoints potential changepoints are selected uniformly from
    the first `changepoint_range` proportion of the history.
  - **changepoint_range**: Proportion of history in which trend changepoints will
    be estimated. Defaults to 0.8 for the first 80%. Not used if
    `changepoints` is specified.
  - **yearly_seasonality**: Fit yearly seasonality.
    Can be 'auto', True, False, or a number of Fourier terms to generate.
  - **weekly_seasonality**: Fit weekly seasonality.
    Can be 'auto', True, False, or a number of Fourier terms to generate.
  - **daily_seasonality**: Fit daily seasonality.
    Can be 'auto', True, False, or a number of Fourier terms to generate.
  - **holidays**: pd.DataFrame with columns holiday (string) and ds (date type)
    and optionally columns lower_window and upper_window which specify a
    range of days around the date to be included as holidays.
    lower_window=-2 will include 2 days prior to the date as holidays. Also
    optionally can have a column prior_scale specifying the prior scale for
    that holiday.
  - **seasonality_mode**: 'additive' (default) or 'multiplicative'.
  - **seasonality_prior_scale**: Parameter modulating the strength of the
    seasonality model. Larger values allow the model to fit larger seasonal
    fluctuations, smaller values dampen the seasonality. Can be specified
    for individual seasonalities using add_seasonality.
  - **holidays_prior_scale**: Parameter modulating the strength of the holiday
    components model, unless overridden in the holidays input.
  - **changepoint_prior_scale**: Parameter modulating the flexibility of the
    automatic changepoint selection. Large values will allow many
    changepoints, small values will allow few changepoints.
  - **mcmc_samples**: Integer, if greater than 0, will do full Bayesian inference
    with the specified number of MCMC samples. If 0, will do MAP
    estimation.
  - **interval_width**: Float, width of the uncertainty intervals provided
    for the forecast. If mcmc_samples=0, this will be only the uncertainty
    in the trend using the MAP estimate of the extrapolated generative
    model. If mcmc.samples>0, this will be integrated over all model
    parameters, which will include uncertainty in seasonality.
  - **uncertainty_samples**: Number of simulated draws used to estimate
    uncertainty intervals. Settings this value to 0 or False will disable
    uncertainty estimation and speed up the calculation.
  - **stan_backend**: str as defined in StanBackendEnum default: None - will try to
    iterate over all available backends and find the working one